# heroku code=H14 when opening app

Tags: heroku

When I try yo open my app I get the following error:

> 2018-06-15T16:32:58.624559+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14
>   desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/"
>   host=bkwiencien.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=81661f5c-c536-412f-bafb-fbc7ae4331

The app is merely some HTML and JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

It means that you have no dynos running. As per the [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h14-no-web-dynos-running), you will need to have at least 1 dyno running your app.

You can do so from the dashboard or Heroku CLI:

`heroku ps:scale web=1`